# Setup wordpress blog to a bigcommerce site

Tags: wordpress, bigcommerce

www.example.com and it's bigcommerce acitivated. I want setup wordpress into blog.example.com,
I uploaded the wordpress and install it into blog.example.com. But It didn't work out. Then I find the link [How do I add a blog to my site using WordPress?](https://support.bigcommerce.com/questions/1181/How+do+I+add+a+blog+to+my+site+using+WordPress) . But I don't want to setup a wordpress.com's blog.
So, How can I setup a wordpress blog into a bigcommerce activated website, or is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely do this. You will need your own hosting for the subdomain. A WordPress blog cannot sit on Bigcommerce's hosting.

1. Set up hosting (on GoDaddy, Bluehost, or other hosting)
2. Install & configure WordPress
3. Make the necessary DNS changes to point the subdomain at your WordPress hosting

This article can walk you through it with a little more detail.
http://inkblotdigital.com/2014/wordpress-blog-bigcommerce-store/

Please clarify with further detail if there is a particular part you are having trouble with as your question is somewhat light on specifics.

Answer (score 1):

I work at Bigcommerce. @DeveloperScott's tips are spot-on, and it's a very straightforward process. But, if you have any questions or find yourself getting stuck at any time, feel free to reply to this thread or ask us a question on Twitter (@bigcommerce). We're here to help you out. :)